# Docker compose with multiple workspaces (different settings)

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file where I have defined some settings like volumes or exposed ports.
Is it possible to define multiple settings (workspace names or something like that)?
For example, in Ubuntu, I want to set the volumes:

- '/app/MyApp/bin/backup:/app/backup'

on Windows it should contain a slightly different path:

- './bin/backup:/app/backup'